# Вылезает Null объект, не знаю как его убрать

Tags: android, kotlin, null

Я пробовал уже и с `!!` и с `?:`, но ничего не помогает справиться с этой проблемой NPE 
Вот код MainActivity

```
package com.example.cars2

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView
import java.sql.Time


class Activity_Information : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity__information)
        Priem_Dannye_Vyvod()
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    fun Priem_Dannye_Vyvod(): Unit? {
        val DannyeSpeed = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.Speed_Dannyee)
        val DannyeTime = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.Time_String)
        val DannyeWay = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.Way_String)
        val intent = intent

        val Time_Priem = intent.getStringExtra("name")
        val Speed_Priem = intent.getStringExtra("name2")
        val Way_Priem = intent.getStringExtra("name3")
        val Time_Priem4 = Time_Priem ?: return null
        val Speed_Priem4 = Speed_Priem ?: return null
        val Way_Priem4 = Way_Priem ?: return null
        val Time_Priem1 = Time_Priem.toInt()
        val Speed_Priem1 = Speed_Priem.toInt()
        val Way_priem1 = Way_Priem.toInt()

        DannyeSpeed.text = Integer.toString(Speed_Priem4)
        DannyeTime.text = Integer.toString(Time_Priem4)
        return DannyeWay.text = Integer.toString(Way_Priem4)
    }
}
```

Принимаю данные из другой Activity, чтобы потом вывести их в EditText. Это данные переменных Speed_Priem4, Time_Priem4, Way_Priem4.

В этих строках пытался избавиться от null, но всё тщетно...

```
val Time_Priem4 = Time_Priem ?: return null
        val Speed_Priem4 = Speed_Priem ?: return null
        val Way_Priem4 = Way_Priem ?: return null
```

Знаю, что ошибка распространенная и глупая, но решить ёё пока никак не могу

Logcat вылетает вот такой:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.cars2, PID: 25424
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.cars2/com.example.cars2.Activity_Information}: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2819)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1558)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6396)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
     Caused by: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
        at com.example.cars2.Activity_Information.Priem_Dannye_Vyvod(Activity_Information.kt:28)
        at com.example.cars2.Activity_Information.onCreate(Activity_Information.kt:15)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6875)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2711)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2819) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1558) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6396) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
```

Comment: что должно делать `val intent = intent`?

Comment: А к чему эта вся движуха: `getStringExtra()` -> `toInt()` и потом обратно `Integer.toString()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Слишком много телодвижений переданными данными. Да и Вам следует почитать, как нужно именовать переменные и методы. Попробуйте изменить код на вот такой:

```
class Activity_Information : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity__information)
        Priem_Dannye_Vyvod()
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    fun Priem_Dannye_Vyvod() {
        val DannyeSpeed = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.Speed_Dannyee)
        val DannyeTime = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.Time_String)
        val DannyeWay = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.Way_String)

        val Time_Priem = intent.getStringExtra("name")
        val Speed_Priem = intent.getStringExtra("name2")
        val Way_Priem = intent.getStringExtra("name3")

        DannyeSpeed.text = Speed_Priem
        DannyeTime.text = Time_Priem
        DannyeWay.text = Way_Priem
    }
}
```